# Find the max date and time from given set of digits in java

Tags: java, datetime

The problem states that there are some random digits given as input and we have to find the maximum date and time in the format MM/DD HH:MM.
Ex:

Input is: 2,2,3,1,3,3,3,5,6,2,0

Output is: 12/30 23:56

I tried the brute force method where each digit is combined with every other digit to form a 2 digit number and so on. But the whole program had around 8 or 9 for loops. Is there a more efficient way to do this??

Edit1:
If no possible month or date or time can be formed then the output  must be 0.
There is no auto insertion of 0s i.e. if you want to form a month 09 then 0 has to be in input and there cannot be repetition of digits.

Comment: Just greedily pick the highest possible number for the first `M`, for the second `M`, etc. A bit of planning-ahead is necessary, though: You can only pick the `1` for the first month-digit if you also have another `1`, `0`, or `2`, and so on.

Comment: This won't work for months 10, 11, and 12.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Why not? I said the highest possible, not the highest, i.e. you would of course not pick `6` for the first M. Or what did you mean?

Comment: There might be a bit of backtracking involved, in case there is no valid combination for the later parts. E.g. if you pick the highest possible date and are then left with 4 digits > 6 for the time.

Comment: @varunj6v1k9 If there does not exist a 0, 1, or 2 in the input, is a 0 inserted by default into the month? E.g. ```[5, 6]``` -> ```06```.

Comment: It’s not obvious that a simpler solution would exist. If you pick, say, 10, for month because it’s the highest possible month number, you may be leaving too many 9s that the rest of the fields can be filled in a valid way. In this case you might have needed 09 for month instead. So you do need to consider very many possibilities before you can make your pick.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a largest date, I can think of something like that (in preudocode):

```
Turn the input digits into a MultiSet // e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiset-interface-guava-java/
for i = 12 to 1 // find the biggest possible month
  try to find if the digits of i are in the multi set. if they are, init the month value & remove them from the multi set.
for d = 31 to 1 // get the biggest possible day
  same
for h = 23 to 1 // get the biggest possible hour
  same
for m = 59 to 1 // get the biggest possible minute
  same
```

Comment: This would not account for needing to put a smaller month to make it valid. If your numbers were 1,2,3,1,2,3,6,1 this code would try to put the month in, followed by the highest day, all the way until it was left with 61 for the minute which is not valid.

Comment: @AgentLu has a very valid point here. A valid result with the above mentioned digits would then be to swap the `3`, `1` and `6` around. `12/16 23:32` would then make the highest valid combination.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 - Calculate the maximum month (in order - 12, 11, 10, 09...).
  - on the remaining digits, search for a *valid* solution.
  - if no valid solution is found, decrease the month to the next highest option.
  - repeat until the maximum month with a valid solution is found.
```

Repeat on each segment in descending order.

The logic is based on 2 facts:

1. It is better to be higher in a high-value segment than in all the lower ones (02/01 00:00 is better than 01/31 23:59).
2. Searching for a valid solution is much faster than searching for the maximum one (you can start from constraints, for example).